# nhibernate, Is there a Java alternative for the .Net QueryOver construction

Tags: java, hibernate

In .Net there is a nHibernate session.QueryOver construction. So it become possible to join objects by using the object properties. I like this 'strong typing' way of working.

To avoiding writing query text,

```
session.createQuery("from Person where name = :n ");
```

Is there a alternative for this construction in java Hibernate (eclipse)?

Thx

Comment: Is [criteria](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) what you want?

Comment: this seems interesting, Example example = Example.create(object),

Comment: further looking, thx for the info